# Singly linked list - deleting/adding item at position x

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

This is about a Singly-linked list. I have the following code. I want to extend these code now so that it's possible to add/delete an element at some specific position. I don't know how to go about implementing it.

This is what I have thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    int amount;
    struct element *first;
};

struct element
{
    int number;
    struct element *next;
    int *temp;
};

int main()
{
    struct list lk;
    struct element *ptr, *temp;
    int amount;
    int i;

    printf("How much elements u want enter?");              
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    ptr = (struct element *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct element));   
    lk.first = ptr;                    
    lk.amount = 0;                      
    printf("Please enter 1. number :");
    scanf("%d", &(ptr->number));                
    temp = ptr;                 

    for (i = 2; i <= amount; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter %d. number", i);
        ptr = (struct element *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct element));
        lk.amount++;                
        scanf("%d", &(ptr->number));
        ptr->next = NULL;           
        temp->next = ptr;           

        temp = ptr;
    }

    ptr = lk.first;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n", ptr->number);
        ptr = ptr->next;

    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I found the following Method, but I dont know how to adjust it for my program:

```
void insertInList (list* L, element* position, element* new)
{   
    if (position == 0)
    {
        new->next = L->first;
        L->first= new;
        L->amount++;
    }
    else
    { 
       new->next = position->next;
       position->next = new;
       L->amount++;
    }
}
```

I tested this after user input:

```
struct list lk;
struct element *ptr, *temp, number1, number2;
int amount;
int i;

printf("Which element u want add:");
scanf("%d", number1.number);


printf("On which position u want add the element?:");
scanf("%d", number2.number);

initList(&lk);
insertInList(&lk, &zahl2, &zahl1);
```

I get an AccessViolentException, after line > `scanf("%d", number1.number);`

Comment: This is very basic staff in data structures, try to dig up more info in the web.

Comment: write a function  `element* findPointerForPosition(list* L, int numberOfPosition)` which will find the pointer which points to the position where you want to insert. Then use the `insertInList` with your list, the pointer `findPointerForPosition` returns and pointer to the element you want to insert.

Comment: You need to write `scanf("%d, &number1.number)` since you need to pass a pointer to an integer to `scanf` and not a value. This leads to an access violation since the value of `number1.number` is interpreted as an address by `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with 2 special cases for your singly-linked non-circular list. The first, a generic way to add data, is simply to continue to add nodes to the end of the list. A function there may look like:

```
/* insert node at end of list */
void insert_end (list *l, int n)
{
    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (l->cnt == 0) 
    {
        l->first = ptr;
        l->cnt++;
        return;
    }

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (iter->next) iter = iter->next;
    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}
```

Above you simply allocate storage for the next element (I have remained them **nodes**). You simply check if the amount (renamed as `cnt`) is `0`. If so, add as first node. If not, then create a **pointer to list** to use as an **iterator** and iterate over the list pointers until `node->next` is `NULL` and add the new node at the end.

(**note:** if insertion efficiency is key, with a double-linked circular list, no iteration is required, you simply add a node at the end by adding at the `list->prev` position, which makes additions blindly fast even in lists with hundreds of millions of nodes)

The next variation is wanting to add a new node at the beginning or start of the list. Here you simply make `ptr->next = l->first` and then `l->first = ptr`:

```
/* insert node at beginning of list */
void insert_start (list *l, int n)
{
    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;

    if (l->cnt == 0) 
        ptr->next = NULL;
    else
        ptr->next = l->first;

    l->first = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}
```

What about inserting a node at a given position in the list. You would need to validate the position `(0 <= pos <= lk->cnt)` (or you could just set any value greater than `lk->cnt` equal to `lk->cnt`). You have already seen how to iterate through the nodes to get to the end of the list using a list pointer to iterate `iter = lter->next` until arriving at the last node. Getting to the `nth` node is no different. To insert at a give position, you are given the position, so it simply becomes a matter of iterating `pos` number of times to reach the insertion point:

```
/* insert node at position */
void insert_pos (list *l, int n, int pos)
{
    /* validate position */
    if (pos < 0 || pos > l->cnt) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid position.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    /* if empty or pos 0, insert_start */
    if (l->cnt == 0 || pos == 0) {
        insert_start (l, n);
        return;
    }

    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (--pos)
        iter = iter->next;

    if (iter->next)
        ptr->next = iter->next;

    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}
```

The next variation is adding a node anywhere in the list in numeric sort order. If the new `ptr->number = 6;` and you already have `5` and `7`, then insert the new `ptr` between those holding `5` and `7`. **Note:** this function below also handles placing the first node, and nodes that are less than the first node in the list, as well as placing nodes at the end of the list. It basically does it all in finding where a given new node will go. You could use this as your only input routine if your goal was to insert nodes in sorted order or you can just use it to fill in special cases.

```
/* insert node at end of list */
void insert_ordered (list *l, int n)
{
    /* if first node of n < first->number */
    if (l->cnt == 0 || n < l->first->number) {
        insert_start (l, n);
        return;
    }

    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (iter->next && n > iter->next->number) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }

    if (iter->next)
        ptr->next = iter->next;

    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}
```

As long as we are expanding your list, you should keep the `main` function clean with functions to `print` the list for you and `free` all memory allocated to the list when you are done. A couple of helper functions that can accomplish this could be:

```
void prn_list (list l)
{
    lnode *ptr = l.first;
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("   node[%2d] : %d\n", i++, ptr->number);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void free_list (list l)
{
    lnode *ptr = l.first;

    while (ptr)
    {
        lnode *del = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free (del);
        del = NULL;
    }
}
```

Deleting works in a similar manner. Putting it all together you get a list that is semi-robust with input features. Note the `struct` have also had `typedefs` created that cut down on the typing and improve readability.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <conio.h>

typedef struct lnode
{
    int number;
    struct lnode *next;
} lnode;

typedef struct
{
    int cnt;
    lnode *first;
} list;

void insert_end (list *l, int n);
void insert_start (list *l, int n);
void insert_ordered (list *l, int n);
void insert_pos (list *l, int n, int pos);
void prn_list (list l);
void free_list (list l);

int main (void)
{
    list lk = { 0, NULL };

    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf ("\n number of nodes to enter: ");              
    scanf ("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int n = 0;
        printf (" enter node[%d]->number: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        insert_end (&lk, n);
    }

    printf ("\n The list contains '%d' nodes.\n", lk.cnt);
    printf ("\n The list nodes are:\n\n");
    prn_list (lk);

    printf ("\n enter number to add at start: ");              
    scanf("%d", &num);
    insert_start (&lk, num);

    printf ("\n The list contains '%d' nodes.\n", lk.cnt);
    printf ("\n The list nodes are:\n\n");
    prn_list (lk);

    printf ("\n enter number to add in order: ");              
    scanf("%d", &num);
    insert_ordered (&lk, num);

    printf ("\n The list contains '%d' nodes.\n", lk.cnt);
    printf ("\n The list nodes are:\n\n");
    prn_list (lk);

    printf ("\n enter number to add at position: ");              
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf ("\n position must be (0 <= pos <= %d)\n", lk.cnt);
    printf ("\n enter position in list for '%d': ", num);
    scanf("%d", &i);
    insert_pos (&lk, num, i);

    printf ("\n The list contains '%d' nodes.\n", lk.cnt);
    printf ("\n The list nodes are:\n\n");
    prn_list (lk);

    printf ("\n Freeing list memory:\n\n");
    free_list (lk);

    //getch();
    return 0;
}

/* insert node at end of list */
void insert_end (list *l, int n)
{
    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (l->cnt == 0) 
    {
        l->first = ptr;
        l->cnt++;
        return;
    }

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (iter->next) iter = iter->next;
    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}

/* insert node at beginning of list */
void insert_start (list *l, int n)
{
    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;

    if (l->cnt == 0) 
        ptr->next = NULL;
    else
        ptr->next = l->first;

    l->first = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}

/* insert node at end of list */
void insert_ordered (list *l, int n)
{
    /* if first node of n < first->number */
    if (l->cnt == 0 || n < l->first->number) {
        insert_start (l, n);
        return;
    }

    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (iter->next && n > iter->next->number)
        iter = iter->next;

    if (iter->next)
        ptr->next = iter->next;

    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}

/* insert node at position */
void insert_pos (list *l, int n, int pos)
{
    /* validate position */
    if (pos < 0 || pos > l->cnt) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid position.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    /* if pos 0, insert_start */
    if (l->cnt == 0 || pos == 0) {
        insert_start (l, n);
        return;
    }

    struct lnode *ptr = NULL;
    if (!(ptr = calloc (1, sizeof *ptr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->number = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    lnode *iter = l->first;  /* pointer to iterate list */

    while (--pos)
        iter = iter->next;

    if (iter->next)
        ptr->next = iter->next;

    iter->next = ptr;
    l->cnt++;
}

/* print all nodes in list */
void prn_list (list l)
{
    lnode *ptr = l.first;
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("   node[%2d] : %d\n", i++, ptr->number);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

/* free memory for all nodes */
void free_list (list l)
{
    lnode *ptr = l.first;

    while (ptr)
    {
        lnode *del = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free (del);
        del = NULL;
    }
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_single_ins

 number of nodes to enter: 3
 enter node[0]->number: 5
 enter node[1]->number: 7
 enter node[2]->number: 9

 The list contains '3' nodes.

 The list nodes are:

   node[ 0] : 5
   node[ 1] : 7
   node[ 2] : 9

 enter number to add at start: 2

 The list contains '4' nodes.

 The list nodes are:

   node[ 0] : 2
   node[ 1] : 5
   node[ 2] : 7
   node[ 3] : 9

 enter number to add in order: 6

 The list contains '5' nodes.

 The list nodes are:

   node[ 0] : 2
   node[ 1] : 5
   node[ 2] : 6
   node[ 3] : 7
   node[ 4] : 9

 enter number to add at position: 4

 position must be (0 <= pos <= 5)

 enter position in list for '4': 4

 The list contains '6' nodes.

 The list nodes are:

   node[ 0] : 2
   node[ 1] : 5
   node[ 2] : 6
   node[ 3] : 7
   node[ 4] : 4
   node[ 5] : 9

 Freeing list memory:
```

**valgrind Memory Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll_single_ins
==22898== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22898== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22898== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22898== Command: ./bin/ll_single_ins
==22898==

number of nodes to enter: 3
enter node[0]->number: 5
enter node[1]->number: 7
enter node[2]->number: 9

The list contains '3' nodes.
<snip>

==22519== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22519==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22519==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 80 bytes allocated
==22519==
==22519== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22519==
==22519== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22519== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function for inserting an element into the list is ok, but I have some suggestions:

- Don't name variables the same as keywords (e.g. new). It will confuse others a lot and I'm not sure if all compilers will allow this...
- In plain C you need to write e.g. `struct list* L` instead of `list* L` (or you add a typedef e.g. `typedef struct list LIST;` which allows you to write LIST *L instead of `struct list* L`).
- Before using pointers always ensure that they are not NULL.
- Add return values to your functions so that the caller can distinguish between success and failure.

I've written the following functions:

```
void initList(struct list* L)
{
    if (L)
    {
        L->amount = 0;
        L->first = NULL;
    }
}

int insertInList(struct list* L, struct element* position, struct element* newElem)
{
    int result = 0;
    struct element *iterator;


    if (L)
    {
        /* Check if newElem is already within list and if so don't add it again! */
        for (iterator = L->first; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->next)
        {
            if (iterator == newElem)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (iterator != newElem)   /* newElem not within list, yet? */
        {
            if (position != 0)
            {
                newElem->next = position->next;
                position->next = newElem;
            }
            else
            {
                newElem->next = L->first;
                L->first= newElem;
            }

            L->amount++;
            result = 1;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}


int deleteFromList(struct list* L, struct element* elem)
{
    int result = 0;
    struct element *iterator;

    if ((L) && (L->amount > 0))   /* list with elements in it? */
    {
        if (L->first != elem)   /* elem is not the first element? */
        {
            /* iterator all items to find entry preceeding elem */
            for (iterator = L->first; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->next)
            {
                if (iterator->next == elem)
                {
                    iterator->next = elem->next;  /* set next element to elemen after elem */

                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            L->first = elem->next;   /* set new head of list */

            result = 1;
        }


        if (result == 1)   /* item deleted? */
        {
            L->amount--;
            elem->next = NULL;   /* ensure next pointer of elem does not point into list! */
        }
    }

    return (result);
}


int deleteIndexFromList(struct list* L, int iElement)   /* iElement is zero based: 0=first element, 1=second element, ... */
{
    int result = 0;
    struct element *iterator;


    if ((L) && (L->amount >= iElement))
    {
        /* iterator all items to find entry preceeding elem */
        for (iterator = L->first; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->next)
        {
            if (iElement == 0)
            {
                result = deleteFromList(L, iterator);
                break;
            }
            iElement--;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}
```

You can test the code with your debugger and the following test programe:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct list L;
    struct element A, B, C, D;


    A.number = 5;
    B.number = 10;
    C.number = 15;
    D.number = 20;


    initList(&L);
    insertInList(&L, NULL, &A);
    insertInList(&L, &A, &B);
    insertInList(&L, &B, &C);
    insertInList(&L, &C, &D);
    /* now your list is 5 -> 10 -> 15 -> 20 */

    deleteFromList(&L, &A);
    /* now your list is 10 -> 15 -> 20 */

    deleteFromList(&L, &C);
    /* now your list is 10 -> 20 */

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, im gonna try this!... but could you also add the method to delete an element at a specific position?

Comment: You mean a function to delete for example the 3rd element?

Comment: I've made some modifications and I've added a new function `deleteIndexFromList`.

Comment: Thanks, i tested the method insertInList, but I get an Exception ... i'm gonna edit my thread opener, with the exception and my code... :)

Comment: Do you know why this is not working? Tell me when u need more information.

Answer (score 0):

For adding an entry after "entry N" you only need to search for "entry N". Then you'd do `new_entry->next = current_entry->next; current_entry->next = new_entry;`.

For adding an entry before "entry N", and for deleting "entry N", you need to keep track of the address of the previous entry while searching; so that when you find "entry N" you still know the address of the previous entry.

In this case deleting "entry N" mostly becomes `previous_entry->next = current_entry->next;`; and inserting a new entry before "entry N" becomes `new_entry->next = previous_entry->next; previous_entry->next = new_entry;`. However, for both of these, for "N == 0" the previous entry may not exist. In that case you have to modify the list's head instead of an entry.

For an example (deleting, where `something` is the name of your structure type):

```
int deleteEntry(int n, something **headPtr) {
    something *previous = NULL;
    something *current = *headPtr;

    while( (current != NULL) && (n > 0) ) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        n--;
    }
    if(current == NULL) {
         return ERROR;    // End of list reached before N found
    }
    if(previous == NULL) {
        *headPtr = current->next;
    } else {
        previous->next = current->next;
    }
    free(current);
    return OK;
}
```

Note: It's entirely possible to handle the `n == 0` case earlier (before the `while` loop). I wrote it like this so that it's easy to modify the search criteria and convert it into something that deletes the first entry that satisfies some other condition.